# Kotlin: SumbyDouble returning additional decimals

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am summing double value from arraylist its giving additional decimals as 99999, how to fix this, please guide

ex

```
class ExDet{var expName:String ="",var expAmount:Double = 0.0}
    val arrayList = ArrayList<ExDet>()
        arrayList.add(ExDet("Abc 1",45.66))
        arrayList.add(ExDet("DEF 1",10.0))
        arrayList.add(ExDet("Lee 1",600.89))  
        arrayList.add(ExDet("Ifr 1",200.9))  

    var amt = arrayList.sumByDouble{ it.expAmount }
```

Expected Value of Amount is :

```
Amt = 857.45
```

But it returns

```
Amt = 857.4499999
```

Sample Code to Test

```
data class ExDet(var expName:String ="" ,var expAmount:Double=0.0)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        val arrayList = ArrayList<ExDet>()
        arrayList.add(ExDet("Abc 1",45.66))
        arrayList.add(ExDet("DEF 1",10.0))
        arrayList.add(ExDet("Lee 1",600.89))  
        arrayList.add(ExDet("Ifr 1",200.9)) 
    var amt = arrayList.sumByDouble{ it.expAmount }

    println("Amount is : $amt")

}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? The patterns in the numbers (3/4 non-dyadic, 1/2 same length base-2 repeats) hints at something a professor would specifically choose to hit this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [issue you are confronted with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error) is that floating point numbers are build on top of base 2, not base 10.

Think how you can easily represent a third as a fraction (1/3), but when you convert to decimal you get a repeating (recurring) number after the radix point (i.e. 0.33...). Some decimal numbers are recurring when represented in base-2, e.g. `x.9`. The computer has a finite number of bits, so the (base-2) number is truncated. All the truncation errors can add up.

You need to round to the required precision (e.g. `round(x * 100) / 100)`.

If you are only interested in how it is displayed then you can use the `format` function with something like "%.2f".

```
String.format("%.2f", value)
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation,Working Fine now